# applying google guice to method dependencies

Tags: java, guice

Consider the following servlet code:

```
public class AddDevice extends JsonServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(final JsonServletRequest request,
            final JsonServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
            IOException {
        try {
            final DeviceEntity device = new DeviceEntity();

            device.type =
                    FleetManagerDatabaseHelper
                            .deviceTypesAccessor()
                            .queryForId(Integer.valueOf(
                                    request.getParameter(DeviceTypeEntity._ID)));

            device.sn = request.getParameter(DeviceEntity._SN);
            device.status = Long.valueOf(0);

            FleetManagerDatabaseHelper.devicesAccessor().create(device);
        }
        catch (final SQLException e) {
            throw new ServletException("device already exists");
        }
    }
}
```

This code depends on the DeviceEntity and on the FleetManagerDatabaseHelper classes.
Now, I would like to write a test for it checking that the created entity is filled with the correct type, sn and status values.
For this purpose I could create a FleetManagerDatabaseHelperMockup class.

How would you apply Google Guice (or something else) here with minimal changes?

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is to design for dependency injection--avoid constructors and static methods, and instead take in instances that you require. It looks like those types are `Provider<DeviceEntity>`, `DevicesAccessor`, and `DeviceTypesAccessor`.

`Provider` is [a very simple Guice interface](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InjectingProviders) that provides instances of whatever class is in its type argument via a single no-arg method `get()`. If you have bound `Foo`, Guice automatically knows how to bind `Provider<Foo>`. It is extremely useful if your instances are expensive, or if you need more than one over the lifetime of your servlet (as you do).

After refactoring for dependency injection, your class will look like this:

```
public class AddDevice extends JsonServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private final Provider<DeviceEntity> deviceEntityProvider;
  private final DevicesAccessor devicesAccessor;
  private final DeviceTypesAccessor deviceTypesAccessor;

  @Inject
  public AddDevice(Provider<DeviceEntity> deviceEntityProvider,
      DevicesAccessor devicesAccessor,
      DeviceTypesAccessor deviceTypesAccessor>) {
    this.deviceEntityProvider = deviceEntityProvider;
    this.devicesAccessor = devicesAccessor;
    this.deviceTypesAccessor = deviceTypesAccessor;
  }

  @Override
  protected void doGet(final JsonServletRequest request,
      final JsonServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
      IOException {
    try {
      final DeviceEntity device = deviceEntityProvider.get();

      device.type = deviceTypesAccessor.queryForId(
          Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter(DeviceTypeEntity._ID)));
      device.sn = request.getParameter(DeviceEntity._SN)
      device.status = Long.valueOf(0);

      devicesAccessor.create(device);
    } catch (final SQLException e) {
      throw new ServletException("device already exists");
    }
  }
}
```

At this point, it's extremely easy to write a test by passing in a Provider that keeps track of the instance it returns, along with a mock DevicesAccessor and a mock DeviceTypesAccessor. (I recommend [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/).) If you write your own Provider interface and remove the `@Inject`, you don't even need to use Guice; in your tests, you could continue to use that constructor, but you would want to satisfy Java EE with a constructor like:

```
public AddDevice() {
  this(new NewDeviceEntityProvider(),
      FleetManagerDatabaseHelper.deviceTypesAccessor(),
      FleetManagerDatabaseHelper.devicesAccessor());
}

private class NewDeviceEntityProvider implements Provider<DeviceEntity> {
  @Override public DeviceEntity get() {
    return new DeviceEntity();
  }
}
```

But if you do want to use Guice to remove that boilerplate, just write a Guice `Module`. Your module would need to bind DeviceTypesAccessor and DevicesAccessor to the instances that FleetManagerDatabaseHelper would return; Guice would see that `DeviceEntity` has a no-arg constructor and would be able to inject `DeviceEntity` and `Provider<DeviceEntity>` automatically. (Comment if you want me to expand on what the `Module` would look like.)

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Adrian Most of that code is your method; the only boilerplate is the series of fields up top, and the constructor that populates them. That is some boilerplate, yes, but saves you in the long run with testability and configurability. Also, though I prefer "constructor injection", you can even skip that by labeling the injected fields with `@Inject` directly.